# Time.sleep in Kivy

Tags: python, delay, kivy

I am looking for some thing like `time.sleep` in Kivy, because kivy does not support `time.sleep` and it hangs when i run a program using `time.sleep`.
I searched and found a function called:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, interval)
```

but its not probably like `time.sleep`. `Clock.schedule` calls a function every x seconds, but I want to make a delay.

[kivy.clock](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html?highlight=clock#)

Comment: what exactly do you want to do after your sleep?

Comment: Im making a Piano and It has a mode that plays songs i want to make delay between every two sounds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> kivy does not support time.sleep

Kivy supports time.sleep just fine, it just doesn't do what you want it to do - as per the function name, it sleeps, which means kivy 'freezes' as it isn't taking input, updating the graphics etc.

Anyway, it sounds like you want `Clock.schedule_once(function, time)`. That will call the function (with a default argument `dt`) in `time` seconds.