# How to use time sleep in Kivy

Tags: kivy

My app just have 1 button. I want to change its color on on_press event and then wait for 5 seconds and then display a popup.

My Attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.2')

from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from random import random
from random import choice
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
import time

my_popup = Popup(title='Test popup',
    content=Label(text='Hello world'),
    size_hint=(None, None))


Builder.load_string("""
<Highest>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Button:
            id: btn_0
            text: "Hi"
            on_press: root.new()
""")

class Highest(Screen):
    def new(self):
        self.ids['btn_0'].background_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
        time.sleep(5)
        my_popup.open()


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Highest(name='Highest'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

But my code, displays popup as well as change color after 5 seconds. Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24993744/time-sleep-in-kivy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kivy, events are scheduled using a [Clock](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) object. In your case, you can use `Clock.schedule_once` to call a callback at any time. Simply re-write your `Highest` class as:

```
class Highest(Screen):
def new(self):
    self.ids['btn_0'].background_color = 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    Clock.schedule_once(my_popup.open, 5)
```

Here you are scheduling `my_popup.open()` in 5 seconds.

Comment: already answered by inclement, anyways i will tick your answer. Thanks